# Converting SQL to X++

Tags: axapta, x++

I would like to convert the following SQL to X++

```
case when CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(NAME)) > 0 then right(NAME,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(NAME))-1) else Name end as Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str result;

result = strScan(name, '-', strLen(name), -strLen(name)) > 0 ?
            strDel(name, 1, strScan(name, '-', strLen(name), -strLen(name))) :
            name;

// Just an observation, the following would actually give the same result

result = strDel(name, 1, strScan(name, '-', strLen(name), -strLen(name)));
```

Please note that such string functions cannot be used in SELECT statements, WHERE clauses, etc. If this is absolutely necessary, the workaround would be to [use computed columns in views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/walkthrough-add-a-computed-column-to-a-view).

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Below is the X++ equivalent for SQL functions:

```
CHARINDEX     strScan
REVERSE       strReverse
RIGHT         subStr
```

[X++ string runtime functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions)

Comment: The equivalent of CHARINDEX is strScan, not strFind. Also, strReverse is not necessary because a signed number in the 4th parameter of both strScan and strFind indicates the direction of the search, something not available in CHARINDEX. Also, strDel can be more convenient than subStr in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this has been fixed